# No increment operator in VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, operators

I am fairly new to vb.net and came across this issue while converting a for loop in C# to VB.net
I realized that the increment operators are not available in vb.net (++ and --)
whereas i was able it do something like `cnt +=1`

I researched a bit and came across [Eric's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/07/19/why-no.aspx) on the same, but wasn't really able to understand fully on it.
He mentions of **In VB, a STATEMENT cannot be just an EXPRESSION.** not sure how that really fits in.

I hope someone here would be able to explain why this doesn't work in the same way as it does in C#.
(Hope this will also hold true as in why we have `==` in C# for comparison)

Comment: -1, It seems that another VB.NET bashing session?

Comment: @Gens It ain't a bash, i am just interested in the why

Comment: The why is explained in that article you linked to. I don't think that you'll get closer to it than that.

Comment: Python is also the same way. Basically, it allows for simpler, easier to parse code and helps prevents cryptic one-liners or unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I would say that the language designers simply thought that ***BASIC*** was a better baseline than C, when designing Visual ***BASIC***. You can follow the lineage of `C` (and, earlier, `BCPL`) through `C++`, `Java` and `C#`.

The `VB` lineage comes from the original `BASIC` from Dartmouth (and, earlier, `Fortran`) and is a different beast altogether.

In other words, what started as the venerable `BASIC`:

```
LET I = I + 1
```

has probably been hacked and destroyed *enough* :-)

As per Eric's post, `i++;` is indeed just an expression, one that yields `i` with the side effect that `i` is incremented after the event  (similar to the non-side-effect expression `i;`).

That's because `C` allows these naked expressions, even things like `42;` which doesn't really do much but is perfectly valid. In other words, the following is a complete `C` program:

```
int main (void) { 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; return 0; }
```

All those expressions are valid but useless (except the `0` at the end of course).

In `BASIC`, this was not really done, because `BASIC` consisted of *statements* (things that did something). That's why `i += 1` (a statement incrementing `i`) is considered okay,  but `i++` (an expression doing nothing which just happens to have a side effect which increments `i`) isn't. You could argue that it's just semantic hair-splitting but that's just the way it is.

You should be thankful for small mercies, at least you're not having to deal with COBOL:

```
ADD 1 TO DD_WS_I.
```

Comment: ok.. Can you please highlight on why its related to the statement vs expression thing (Sorry i have very insignificant knowledge of VB, please do suggest if i have no anything in particular from the VB background)

Comment: I'm not quite sure how I stumbled upon this question, but great answer.

Comment: Surely Add LS-VAL-01 TO WS-VAL-DD GIVING WS-VAL-DD-NEW. Or even better, COMPUTE ... GIVING

Comment: I'm dealing with VB.NET and COBOL

Answer (score 10):

Simply because the designers thought that `i++` is unnecessary when you have `i += 1`.

`For` loops don't need either one, so you don't lose anything.

It's Visual **Basic** after all... why make it complicated?

Comment: and they didn't think that in case of C# ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta: No, because it was designed to be similar to C/C++.

Comment: I would disagree - you can't use `i += 1` in any expression context either, whereas in C++, `++i` and `i += 1` can be part of a larger expression (e.g. `a[++i] = (b += 2);`).

Answer (score 6):

As @paxdiablo said, in VB (or rather, in its ancestor BASIC), everything used to be a *statement*. And in fact, every statement was introduced by a keyword.

So to assign a variable we had

```
LET x = x + 1
```

and to call a method, we had

```
CALL SomeMethod
```

In VB, the `LET` and `CALL` were finally dropped (except in one special circumstance) because it’s completely redundant and doesn’t add clarity. But the underlying lexical grammar of VB didn’t change all that much: each statement still has to be a *statement*. `i++` isn’t a statement in VB, since it lacks either a function call or an assignment.

There was an argument in the first version of VB.NET whether to introduce pre- and post-increment operators like in C#. It was decided not to do this, for a fairly simple reason: using side-effects in expressions isn’t recommended anyway. It usually lets clarity suffer. So even in C# legitimate uses of `i++` *in an expression* are very rare, and legitimate uses of `++i` are rarer still (though I won’t deny that in some cases it *adds* clarity).

In most cases you can use `i += 1` just fine and this perfectly well expresses the intent.

Notice that in C++, the situation is fundamentally different because here (but *not* in C#!) `i++` actually has a *different semantic* than `i += 1` due to operator overloading (in C# we also have operator overloading but `++` cannot be overloaded).

Answer (score 5):

As an example of the difference between expression and statement in VB,
in VB the following generates a compiler error since `count += 1` increments `count` by 1, but the whole expression `count += 1` does not return a result, so it can't be used as a parameter.

```vb
Dim count As Integer = 0
Console.WriteLine(count += 1)  ' compiler error
```

You have to do this instead

```
Dim count As Integer = 0
count += 1
Console.Writeline(count)
```

Of course same applies to using the `+=` operator on a String.

#### What does "In VB, a statement cannot just be an expression" mean?

- The VB compiler requires results to be consumed in some assignment or other operation.
- Because of this an assignment operation in VB does **not** produce a result. If it did the VB compiler would not allow it to stand alone as a statement (the compiler requires results be consumed).
- Thus assignments in VB can be used as statements, but not as expressions. That is you cannot use an assignment statement as a parameter to a method, or as an intermediate result.
- In C# an assignment operation **does** produce a value. Thus in order for assignments to stand alone as statements, the compiler does **not** require all results to be consumed.
- The corollary in C# is that any other operation that produces a result can stand alone as a statement. `2 + 2` for instance produces the result `4` and can stand alone as a statement, whereas in VB it can't.

#### Simplified answer to "Why are pre and post increment operators not available in VB?"

`count++` says, **first** return the value of `count`, **then** increment `count` (and do not return the value of the assignment to `count`).
In this case the incremented value is not used (the value before incrementing is used). As mentioned before, the VB compiler requires you use or assign values of operations.

`++count` says, **first** increment `count`, **then** return the value of the assignment to `count`.
In this case, the value of assigning +1 to `count` is returned as the value of the expression. As mentioned before, assignments in VB do not produce a result.
Thus there would be some serious pain implementing these operators in VB.

Answer (score 4):

The following extension methods replicate `++x` `x++` `--x` `x--`

```
Public Module INC_DEC

  <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
  Public Function PreINC(ByRef x As Integer) As Integer
    Return Interlocked.Increment(x)
  End Function

  <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
  Public Function PostINC(ByRef x As Integer) As Integer
    Dim tmp = x
    Interlocked.Increment(x)
    Return tmp
  End Function

  <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
  Public Function PreDEC(ByRef x As Integer) As Integer
    Return Interlocked.Decrement(x)
  End Function

  <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
  Public Function PostDEC(ByRef x As Integer) As Integer
    Dim tmp = x
    Interlocked.Decrement(x)
    Return tmp 
  End Function
End Module
```

Comment: new favorite abomination in VB.net. Thanks @AdapSpeight for the laugh today!