# How would you write this in VB.net? I don't get index++

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Really trivial I suppose, but I don't understand what index++ does. How would this be written in VB.net?

```
int index = 0;
foreach(String prop in props.Keys)
{
     pSpec.pathSet[index++] = prop;
}
pSpecs.Add(pSpec);
```

Comment: I don't know VB.net but index++ will just increment the value of index, so you could image it as index = index + 1. http://cplus.about.com/od/glossar1/g/postincdefn.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim index As Integer = 0
For Each prop As [String] In props.Keys
    index = index +1
    pSpec.pathSet(index) = prop
Next
pSpecs.Add(pSpec)
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `System.Math.Min(...)` instead?

Comment: Your code is not the same as in question. Incrementation should be after assignment.

Comment: You've changed the meaning - effectively you've create a pre-increment rather than a post-increment.

Comment: The answer is correct, but the increment does need to be after the assignment. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

It's just a post-increment. Meaning it will return it's value and then increase it's value by 1.

```
pSpec.pathSet[index++] = prop;
```

in VB.net would most likely be just:

```
pSpec.pathSet[index] = prop
index = index + 1 // this would work
index += 1 // this would work too
```

It's just important to note that you can't do it inline that way (as you'll need the previous value).

Answer (score 2):

The increment operator `(++)` increments its operand by 1. The increment operator can appear before or after its operand:

It's is the same `index = index +1;`

Comment: This will always be at index 1

Comment: `index = index++` won't do what you think (try it). It should just be `index++` or `index = index + 1` or `index += 1`

Comment: You're right. I never noticed before, I wonder why though.  edit: I just found out :). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well you will have to increment it in this fashion

```
index =index + 1;
```

or `index +=1`

If interested why [no increment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339442/no-increment-operator-in-vb-net)

Got this [using this](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)

```
Dim index As Integer = 0
For Each prop As [String] In props.Keys
    pSpec.pathSet(System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(index),index - 1)) = prop
Next
pSpecs.Add(pSpec)
```

Answer (score 0):

index++ will increment index by 1.

I don't know much VB but you could do:

```
index = index + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`index++` returns the current value of `index` and after that, it increments the value of `index`.

In the first iteration, it will return 0 as value, and after it the value will be increased to 1.
In the second iteration, it will return 1 as value, and after it the value will be increased to 2.

The '++' operator doesn't exist in VB, you have to increment it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for

```
Dim index As Integer = 0
For Each prop As [String] In props.Keys
    pSpec.pathSet(System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(index),index - 1)) = prop
Next
pSpecs.Add(pSpec)
```

Answer (score 0):

index++ increments the value of index by 1. That syntax is not available in VB.NET (http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/paulvick.html)

so index++ is the equivalent of index = index+1
your vb code should be something like:

```
{
 index = index+1
 pSpec.pathSet[index] = prop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned this just increments the value.

++ is not a valid operator in VB.NET but the closest thing is probably:

```
index += 1
```

This was a nice change for anyone coming from VB6 because before we had to always use the longhand `index = index + 1`