# What's __PostIncrement in decompiled VB (by ILSpy)

Tags: vb.net, cil, decompiling, ilspy

I was just perusing the decompiled code for `System.Collections.Generic.List(Of T).Add(item As T)` using ILSpy and I found a call to `__PostIncrement`.  I've never heard of such a thing in VB, so I did some digging and found:

1. In VB, the code is `Me._items(__PostIncrement(Me._size)) = item`.
2. In C#, the code is `this._items[this._size++] = item;` using the actual post-increment operator in that language
3. In MSIL, *there is not* a function call.  It appears to work like a C# post-increment would (the comments are mine, but I'm no expert at MSIL,so I could be wrong).

The code is:

```
IL_001e: ldarg.0
IL_001f: ldfld !0[] class System.Collections.Generic.List`1<!T>::_items
IL_0024: ldarg.0
IL_0025: dup
IL_0026: ldfld int32 class System.Collections.Generic.List`1<!T>::_size
IL_002b: dup
IL_002c: stloc.0           // store the size pre incrementing
IL_002d: ldc.i4.1
IL_002e: add               // do the increment
IL_002f: stfld int32 class System.Collections.Generic.List`1<!T>::_size
IL_0034: ldloc.0           // reload the stored size to use as index in stelem
IL_0035: ldarg.1
IL_0036: stelem.any !T
```

What exactly is this `__PostIncrement`?  Is it a SharpDevelop invention to symbolize post-increment IL code in VB?  Or is it actually some kind of definition I could use in my own VB code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

__PostIncrement is the equivalent of the C# [`operator++`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/36x43w8w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It is a quick way to increment (add one) to a number. Unfortunately, according to the [list of operators in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6ex274z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), there is no equivalent.

Comment: It's defined in the VB language spec somewhere so I can use it in my code as well?

Comment: Updated the answer to say that VB does not appear to support either the prefix or postfix versions of either the `++` or `--` operators.

Comment: I know that.  That's my question.  Why is ILSpy decompiling to `__PostIncrement` if no such thing exists?

Comment: Because it exists in IL. The library was probably written in C# which supports the operator and then called from VB in your code (and examined by ILSpy). As for the why, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339442/no-increment-operator-in-vb-net.

Comment: @just.another.programmer The alternative is a hard error for any function that cannot be accurately decompiled to VB.NET. There is no VB.NET code that results in the IL in your question.

Comment: What do you mean it *exists* in IL?  Do you mean specifically the `dup` OpCode which C# uses to create the non-saved copy of the increment variable?  I could reproduce the *effect* of that in VB (by creating my own local variable, or with a method call), but I don't know if I could reproduce the actual `dup`...