# Increment Integer by one

Tags: vb.net

When creating messages in C# I've done something similar to this.

```
            ByteMessage[i] = "A"
            ByteMessage[++i] = "B"
            ByteMessage[++i] = "C"
            ......................
```

I would like to accomplish this in VB.NET, except VB.NET does not support the `++` or `--` operators. I've tried things like

```
            ByteMessage(i += 1) = "A"
            ByteMessage(i += 1) = "B"
            ByteMessage(i += 1) = "C"
            ......................
```

But this doesn't seem to work.  The `MATH` library didn't seem to have anything in it either for use.

Is there any clean solution for this in VB.NET like there is for C#?

Comment: Pretty sure you will have to do the operations outside of the parentheses. ByteMessage(i) = "A". i +=1. ByteMessage(i) = "B". etc. See this answer on another question for better explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7072634/7919626

Comment: You can't do the same in VB.NET.  There's is no pre-or post-increment operator.  You have to do the incrementing in separate expressions.

Comment: If you explain further what you're trying to accomplish then you could still get a useful answer

Comment: @AFriend I just want to accomplish incrementing the integer `i` by one inside the parenthesis of the array using VB.NET.

Comment: Pretty fundamental difference between vb.net and the curly-brace languages.  i += 1 is a *statement*, not an expression.  This is not exactly an arbitrary limitation, it allows the vb.net compiler to generate better error messages for syntax errors.  You'll have to hoof it with i+1, i+2, etc.  Making it DRY with a for-loop isn't going to hurt your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing inherent in .Net that supports pre/post increment and return functionality.  The C# compiler supports its by emitting the required IL statements when it compiles the code.  While VB.Net language developers did not deem this feature necessary, there is nothing that prevents you from using [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/extension-methods) to add this functionality.

The only limitation is that you need to use valid method name (for example `IncrPre` or `IncrPost`) for the extension method and use method notation instead of the `++i` or `i++` notation.

```
Public Module Int32Extensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Function IncrPost(ByRef i As Int32) As Int32
        Dim ret As Int32 = i
        i += 1
        Return ret
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Function IncrPre(ByRef i As Int32) As Int32
        i += 1
        Return i
    End Function
End Module
```

Example usage:

```
Dim i As Int32 = 0
Dim ByteMessage As String() = New String(0 To 4) {}
ByteMessage(i) = "A"
ByteMessage(i.IncrPre) = "B"
ByteMessage(i.IncrPre) = "C"
i = 3
ByteMessage(i.IncrPost) = "D"
ByteMessage(i) = "E"
```

yields:

[image]

Comment: That's a pretty slick solution to this.  It keeps it pretty clean too.

Answer (score 0):

You can still do what you need to do inside your parenthesis. You can create some extensions as it already has been mentioned, create a function to do it for you that returns the value you need or do it directly inside the parenthesis without any functions or extensions.

Alternative solution below without separate function, new extensions, etc...

```
    Dim i As Int32 = 0
    Dim ByteMessage As String() = New String(0 To 5) {}
    Dim CharLetters As Char() = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}

    ByteMessage(If(Integer.TryParse((CStr(i)), i), i, 0)) = CharLetters(i)
    ByteMessage(If(Integer.TryParse((CStr(i + 1)), i), i, 0)) = CharLetters(i)
    ByteMessage(If(Integer.TryParse((CStr(i + 1)), i), i, 0)) = CharLetters(i)
    ByteMessage(If(Integer.TryParse((CStr(i + 1)), i), i, 0)) = CharLetters(i)

    MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, ByteMessage))

    i = 4

    ByteMessage(If(Integer.TryParse((CStr(i)), i), i, 0)) = CharLetters(i)
    ByteMessage(If(Integer.TryParse((CStr(i + 1)), i), i, 0)) = CharLetters(i)

    MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, ByteMessage))
```

[image]